# Cannot find fax machine on Chrome browser on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, google-chrome, printers, fax, network-printers

I have HP multi-function printers (4301fdw, 477dw) that can send faxes, and they both work under Safari, Firefox, and preview, but on Google Chrome I can find printers only, but not fax machine.

I understand fax is not a popular app, so if you use Mac, chrome, and fax, please help, thanks!

Comment: Use the system print interface, I am able to find printers as well as fax machines.